# Is this a UDEVMON or YAML question?

Tags: keyboard

Given instructions to create a udevmon configuration file in /etc/udevmon.yaml with content:

```
- JOB: intercept -g $DEVNODE | y2z | x2y | uinput -d $DEVNODE
  DEVICE:
    EVENTS:
      EV_KEY: [KEY_X, KEY_Y]
```

does the yaml processor figure out what DEVNODE should be based on KEY_Y and/or KEY_Y or does DEVNODE need to be established prior to yaml processor being started. I think the latter but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is the former! I accidentally learned this via a computer restart. Prior to the restart, nothing I did would trigger udevmon to activate. But after a restart, I noticed it was working which meant that the device was deduced. My experiments at setting DEVNODE were limited to the shell I created for testing. There was no DEVNODE variable in my .bash_login file.